# RemoveLastWord Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I tried to remove the last word of a given string but it doesn't work and i don't know why could someone help me please

[picture of function remove last word and error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApTzA.png)

[second try function remove last word and different error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsyUL.png)

difference between first and second picture is that i used

no space in lastIndexOf

```
text.lastIndexOf('');
```

and in the second try i used:

space in lastIndexOf

```
text.lastIndexOf(' ');
```

i could not get it working.

can someone help me please ?

code of my program.

```
function removeLastWord(text) {
    newtext = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(' '));
    return newtext;
}
```

the error is in the picture

Comment: Please post your actual code not the picture.

Comment: The function seems to be working fine, but from the picture I guess the function is expected to return `'A'` on `removeLastWord('A')` instead of `''`.

Comment: the problem is that my code doesnt work on singular line codes that it just needs to return the text if its just one word

Comment: Use `let newtext = ... ` to avoid global leak(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take the string, split it by a space, which will turn it into array of words, then slice from that array the last entry (last words) and join them back with a space.

Here is the code:

```js
words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet anim id est laborum.";
exceptLast = words.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");
```

And this is the result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet anim id est
```

Everything except the last word. Making it into a function and testing it with extreme values (single word, empty string) works well too:

```js
function removeLastWord(input) {
    if ( (typeof input === 'string') && input.length > 0) {
        if (input.split(" ").length == 1) {
            // Single word input, just return it as it is
            return input
        } else {
            // Multiple words in the string, remove the last word
            return  input.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");
        }
    } else {
        // Invalid input, just return ''
        return '';
    }
}

removeLastWord("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet anim id est laborum.");
removeLastWord("Lorem");
removeLastWord("");
removeLastWord('');
removeLastWord('A');
removeLastWord('Hallo');
```

From your description in the comments you do not want to remove the last word, when there is only one word int the text, so you can just have condition for that, so you can do everything you want, when you describe it in the code.

Comment: your code gives the same result as picture one in my question.

Comment: Please do not paste pictures, when you should paste code snippets. You have some unit testing framework? You gave us 0 information about it. I made work in JavaScript as you made the question in a JavaScript tag, are there some more constraints you didn't give us in the question?

Comment: i cant see the test code from my professor. i dont know how to post that

Comment: ```expect(removeLastWord('A')).to.be.equal('A');``` and ```expect(removeLastWord('Hallo')).to.be.equal('Hallo');``` this is the error i am getting

Comment: your code and my code doesnt work on single word strings and i dont know why

Comment: if its a single word it should not be deleted.

Comment: I couldn't really known what you wanted it to do because you didn't formulated properly the question (screenshot usually confuse more people, compared to the code). First I was thinking you want to remove the last word even when it's the only word, so I updated the answer with conditions and now the single word is returning back itself without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
function removeLast(str){
    return str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(" "))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach using regular expression

```js
function removeLastWord(text) {
    return text.replace(/(\s+([^\s]|\n|\r)+)$/g, "");
}
```